# Push array object into another array object in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm getting an error while pushing one object into another object. But the 2nd object is an array and inside an array there is an object. How can I fix this cause I want to add that into my object

My object just like this

I want to add the the **Object2** into **Object1**

**Objet1**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id_laporan_pemeriksa] => 5
    [no_pkpt] => SNE
    [tgl_pkpt] => 2010
    [no_penugasan] => ST-4000/PW25/2/2017
    [tgl_penugasan] => 2017-08-09
    [judul_laporan] => Masukkan Kode disini
    [no_laporan] => LBINA-9000/PW25/2/2017
    [tgl_laporan] => 2017-08-01
    [tahun_anggaran_penugasan] => 2009
    [nilai_anggaran_penugasan] => 10000000
    [realisasi_anggaran_penugasan] => 100000000
    [jenis_anggaran_penugasan] => Utang
    [sumber_laporan] => Inspektorat Maluku
    [nama_sumber_penugasan] => PKPT
    [nama_ketua_tim] => Abdul Rofiek, Ak.
    [nama_pengendali_teknis] => Alfian Massagony, S.E.
    [nama_unit_penugasan] => Irban Wil. I
    [nama_penugasan] => Penjaminan
    [nama_sub_penugasan] => Audit
    [id_s_sub_penugasan] => 010105
    [nama_s_sub_penugasan] => Audit atas hal-hal lain di bidang kepegawaian.
)
```

**Object2**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 3
    [data_sebab] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [data_rekomendasi] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 4

                                    [data_tindak_lanjut] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 9

                                                    [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 0000-00-00
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 5
                                    [id_rekomendasi] => 
                                    [data_tindak_lanjut] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 10
                                                    [id_tindak_lanjut] => 
                                                    [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 0000-00-00
                                                )

                                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 11
                                                    [id_tindak_lanjut] => 
                                                    [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 0000-00-00
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I have tried

```
  $Object1['data']->$Object2;
```

But i got an error

> **Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of adding `$Object2` as a property of `$Object1` is:

```
$Object1->Object2 = $Object2;
```

Or:

```
$Object1->{'Object2'} = $Object2;
```

Comment: Okay, this syntax works. but i got an array instead when i am push it into Object1.  i want it to be stdClassObject
And how do i change the entire object2 into an array ?

Comment: You can use `(array)$object`.

Comment: i must add (object) for each ['data_sebab'],[data_rekomendasi],and [data_tindak_lanjut] array to become object ? or there is a why to change them all at once ? ? i have added this $Object1->Object2 = (object) $Object2; but its only the Object2 array that changed, not the inside array @Marty

Comment: You can hackishly do something like `$Object1 = json_decode(json_encode($Object1))`.

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks
And sorry marty, in my first question i said " how do i change the entire object2 into an array?"  the correct sentence was " how do i change the entire object2 into an object?" i can't edit the first comment because, maybe i have edited the first comment too often @Marty

Comment: how do i call the data ? 
for example if i want to echo ['data_tindak_lanjut'], how do i do that ? 
And all inside ['Object1'] is an object (Stdclass Object ) since i have changed them all from array to object. Or do you have a suggestion how do i suppose to with these data ?

Comment: `$Object->data->whatever->other->nested->stuff->you->want`

Comment: getting issue with [0] => StdClassObject, it returns
Syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)
when i am trying $Object->data->0->id

Comment: `$Object->{'0'}->id`

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
$Object1->data = $Object2; // it will create data element with obj2 as value
```

Answer (score 1):

As the objects are objects and not arrays, using:

```
$Object1['data']->$Object2;
```

wont work. However doing the following will work:

```
$Object1->data = $Object2;
```